# In Google, is there an embedded plagiarism checker?

Tags: google-docs, google-classroom, google-workspace

Is there a way to use a plagiarism checker in Google? I am writing a research project and I do not want to have an issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a G Suite for Education account you could join the beta of **Originality Reports** in Google Assignments and/or Google Classroom.

If you only have a regular Google account, there isn't yet.

References

- https://edu.google.com/assignments/
- [Originality reports for Google Classroom and Google Assignments launching to beta](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/08/originality-reports-edu.html)